# Maximum likelihoof estimator of $\mu$ if $X_1\sim N(\mu,1)$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Question: Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be a random sample with $X_1 \sim N(\mu, 1)$ where $\mu \geq 0$. Derive the
maximum likelihood estimator of $\mu$.

---

I have some difficulties understanding the question.

I already calculated the MLE of $\mu$ when $X_1,...,X_n$ are a random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. In that case the MLE of $\mu$ is $\hat{\mu} = \bar{X}$.

Is it the same case here? Or does the $\mu\geq 0$ changes anything? Or maybe the question states that $X_2,...,X_n\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$? I'm not that familiar with statistic jargon.

Comment: It is the same. Changing the variance($\sigma^2$) doesn’t change the mean. The change in variance only describes the ”width”.

Comment: This is a constrained optimization problem; the likelihood behaves differently here and that will be reflected in the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that $\sigma^2 =1$ slightly simplifies the calculation of the log-likelihood and the maximum likelihood estimator of $\mu$.  But that is only part of the answer.

If $\bar X \le 0$ then knowing $\mu \ge 0$ means using $\hat \mu = \bar X$ would have zero likelihood. In such a case, you can do the analysis, but it is intuitively obvious that $\hat \mu = 0$ would maximise the likelihood.  If you need to combine the results then you could say the maximum likelihood estimator is $$\hat \mu = \max(0, \bar X).$$

Comment: Based on what mathematical information that you replace $\mu<0$ by $0$?

Comment: @NN2 You said you wanted the $\mu$ which minimises  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2$, but here you are subject to the constraint $\mu \ge 0$.  That can be rewritten as  $n(\mu-\bar x)^2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i^2) - n\bar x^2$ which, when $\bar x <0$, is an increasing function of non-negative $\mu$ and so minimised when $\mu$ is $\hat \mu=0$.

Comment: Ok I see now...

Answer (score 1):

For a sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, the likelihood function is
$$\mathcal L(\mu \mid \boldsymbol x) \propto \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-(x_i - \mu)^2/2} = \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 \right).$$  Thus the log-likelihood is
$$\ell(\mu \mid \boldsymbol x) = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2, \tag{1}$$ which, being the sum of squares, is always nonpositive.  Thus its maximum is attained when $\sum (x_i - \mu)^2$ is minimized.  But we may write
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x + \bar x - \mu)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 + 2(x_i - \bar x)(\bar x - \mu) + (\bar x - \mu)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 + 2(\bar x - \mu) \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x) + \sum_{i=1}^n (\bar x - \mu)^2 \\
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 \right) + n(\bar x - \mu)^2, \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
since $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n \bar x$$ by definition implies $$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x) = 0.$$

Thus, $(2)$ is the sum of a term that is constant with respect to $\mu$, and a term that varies with $\mu$ in relation to a fixed value $\bar x$.  If we can choose $\mu = \bar x$, this is the global minimum of $(2)$.  However, if $\bar x < 0$, then such a choice is disallowed.  In such a case, we write

$$(\bar x - \mu)^2 = (\mu + (-\bar x))^2$$

and since $-\bar x > 0$ and we require $\mu \ge 0$, it becomes obvious that $\mu = 0$ is the choice that minimizes $(\mu + (-\bar x))^2$.

Therefore, the (restricted) maximum likelihood estimator is given by $$\hat \mu = \max(0, \bar x).$$